# Why does the to_java method convert (what would be) an integer in Java, to Long?

Tags: ruby, interop, jruby, rubymine

Why does the to_java method convert the integral value of 1 to the Java::JavaLang::Long class, instead of the Integer calss?

Here is an example of this method in action:

```
puts 1.to_java.class
```

In normal Java, the value 1, if placed in a wrapper class, would be a memeber of Java.lang.Integer (correct me if I am wrong). Why, in Ruby, is 1.to_java a member of Java::JavaLang::Long?

Comment: The conversion seems to be based on the object's class (`Fixnum`), not the object itself.

Comment: In that case, why are all objects of class FixNum, when converted to Java, not members of Java::JavaLang::Integer

Comment: It seems to be some sort of auto promotion, since all Integers in Java can also be Longs. But I would appreciate someone providing a more refined answer.

Comment: Fixnum represent numbers that can fit into one machine word. On 64 bit computers, this can exceed that Java integer limit. Technically, it could also exceed the Long limit, if the word size was greater than 64-bits, but that's not a problem we currently have.

Comment: What is the maximum number of one machine word for a 64 bit system? Just curious.

Comment: @AdamJ According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)), the maximum 64-bit signed value would be _9,223,372,036,854,775,808_. In the ruby docs for [Fixnum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html), the first sentence corroborates what Max said. Also, as a side experiment, I'd be curious to see what `to_java` does with `Bignum` values; do they get converted to `BigInteger` class objects?

Comment: Interesting idea. I can test this theory in a bit, and report back.

Comment: @PaulRichter: Those are the docs for YARV's `Fixnum` class. JRuby's `Fixnum`s are actually bigger. YARV's `Fixnums` are 31 bit or 63 bit signed 2-complement integers depending on the CPU architecture, JRuby's are always 64 bit signed 2-complement integers, regardless of CPU architecture. Note that the Ruby Language Specification only talks about arbitrary sized `Integer`s, having fixed-size `Fixnum`s is a private implementation detail of the Ruby implementation that is not guaranteed to have a certain size, certain behavior or even exist *at all*! IMO, they should have never been exposed to …

Comment: … the programmer in the first place, just like YARV's flonums.

Comment: I ran `x = 4611686018427387904*3

puts x.to_java.class`, and the resulting class is `Java::JavaMath::BigInteger`. This seems to be analgous to Java's Bigint class: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_biginteger.htm

Comment: Also, I am using Rubymine and Jruby, so I am running this code over the JVM instead of YARV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply because `Fixnum` in JRuby is represented internally as a (primitive) long field (check RubyFixnum.java) thus by default `Fixnum#to_java` simply returns it's internal Java value

same goes for `Bigint` - internally represented as BigInteger so you get one using `to_java`

... you can provide a conversion hint: `1.to_java(:int).class # Java::JavaLang::Integer`